# wso2-am v210 publish APIS with Hot Deployment

Tags: wso2-api-manager, hotdeploy

i want to publish APIS to the store by hot deployment/hot update without GUI.

Is there a feature like copy a yaml/xml to a specific Directory or is it possible to do this with the AdminServices?

If yes, how could i configure it?

Thanks for time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment. If you use API [import/export](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment) you can create the API. But you need to manually publish the API. By doing this you don't need to create the API from the scratch.

Comment: Ok, publish seems to be to much. Maybe creating an API ist ok for me. Do you know if creating is possible with the Admin Services? It would be nice, because the developers in the team could generate wsdls or xmls and are searching an easy way to put them to the store. Publishing all the APIs by another developer may be a process that works.

Comment: For Example the wsdl of /services/RestApiAdmin seems to be interesting. I thought with the Method addApi  ist ist able do add a RestAPI to the store.

Comment: Available APIs are https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Published+APIs. Maybe you can use these.